# Response of fetching binary data in Postman is successful, but in console returns undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to fetch binary from API using POST request.

```
const generateReportData = async (params: ReportParams) => {
    const response = await fetchReportService(
        { path: "GenerateReport", method: "POST", body: params }).catch();
    console.log(response, 'RESP'); // returns undefined for some reason;
    const blob = new Blob([response], { type: "application/octet-stream" });
    const fileName = "report.doc";
    saveAs(blob, fileName);
};

export const fetchReportService = ({ path, method, query, body, options = {} }: FetchParams) => {
    return fetch(Config.api.report, path, {
        headers,
        method,
        body: body ? JSON.stringify(body) : undefined,
        ...options,
    }, query);
};
```

In this method is `response` undefined for some reason. However if I check my network tab, the request has 200 code and the response looks like this:
[image]

I need this response to be accessible from my code. Any ideas why is the `response` in my method undefined?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: what is `fetchReportService`?

Comment: @NikitaMazur its basically fetch function. It defines route, headers, method and so on. I'm gonna edit my code so you can see it.

Comment: It's na object with necessary parameters for the POST function to return value.

Comment: try removing .catch() it doesnt work with async/await and is probably the reason you got undefined

Comment: @NikitaMazur doesn't solve the problem unfortunately

Comment: Hm strange, it runs in browser? I mean client-side, not server side (SSR)? Try to console the fetch before you call it

Comment: If I console.log the fetch it is still undefined.

Answer (score 1):

Update:

It is weird that you got `undefined`. From the code you post you should get at least something non-null.

I'd advice you to do the following to debug:

1. remove the tailing empty `.catch()`
2. `const response = fetchReportService(...)` **without** await keyword, then `console.log` it to make ensure it's an instance of `Response` builtin class.
3. If it's still `undefined`, then you should verify that `fetch === window.fetch` inside `fetchReportService`. You might mistakenly `import fetch from 'somewhere'` and using a wrong fetch function.
4. Might as well verify that `window.fetch.toString() == "function fetch() { [native code] }"`, to ensure your runtime is not tampered.

---

Original answer:

This line is problematic.

```
const blob = new Blob([response], { type: "application/octet-stream" });
```

If you don't care about the MIME type and simply wanna obtain the binary blob from the response, you can do:

```
const blob = await response.blob();
```

Or, you can construct the blob manually from arrayBuffer.

```
const blob = new Blob([await response.arrayBuffer()], { type: "application/octet-stream" });
```

Comment: Well I can't really do much with response since its undefined. Thats the whole point of this question.

Comment: @AdamŠulc I list some debug advices

Comment: Eventually fixed the issue with your help, had to change the fetch function for the particular API call.

Answer (score 0):

You need remove '.catch()'

```js
const generateReportData = async (params: ReportParams) => {
    try {
        const response = await fetchReportService(
            { path: "GenerateReport", method: "POST", body: params });
        console.log(response, 'RESP'); // returns undefined for some reason;
        const blob = new Blob([response], { type: "application/octet-stream" });
        const fileName = "report.doc";
        saveAs(blob, fileName);
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e)
    }
};

export const fetchReportService = ({ path, method, query, body, options = {} }: FetchParams) => {
    return fetch(Config.api.report, path, {
        headers,
        method,
        body: body ? JSON.stringify(body) : undefined,
        ...options,
    }, query);
};
```

Comment: OP stated it doesn't resolve his problem unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

The Fetch API call is asynchronous.

Example with async/await:

```
  export const fetchReportService = async ({ path, method, query, body, options = {} }: FetchParams) => {
    try {
      const res = await fetch(Config.api.report, path, {
        headers,
        method,
        body: body ? JSON.stringify(body) : undefined,
        ...options,
      }, query);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }

    return res;
  };
```